# Are there any kind of references to a member variable?

Tags: c++, class, reference, member-variables

I've tried to do a reference to a member variable, and understood that it does not work. Are there any way to do this? If not, is there a way to not constantly write "(* this)." ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
private:
    std::string str_m;

    void doSomething()
    {
        std::string& str = (*this).str_m;      // does not work
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    }

public:
    Test(std::string str): str_m(str)
    {
        (*this).doSomething();
    }

};

int main()
{
    Test test{"aaa"};
    return 0;
}
```

VS compiler gave me: error C3867:  'Test::doSomething': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: the way to not constantly write `(*this)` is to simply not do it....

Comment: Where have you got such code style from: `(*this).doSomething();`

Comment: I meant to refer to variables

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/yimyDE)

Comment: The error message does not match your code. You are not using `Test::doSomething` anywhere. The code is functional, but unusual, since you can just write `->` instead of `*` followed by `.` or drop the `this` explicit reference completely.

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried to do a reference to a member variable, and understood that it does not work. Are there any way to do this?

Yes:

```
struct Test {
    std::string str_m;
    void doSomething()
    {
        std::string& str = str_m;
    }
};
```

> [If not], is there a way to not constantly write "(* this)." ?

It is not clear from where you got the idea that you would have to write `(*this).member`. If you want to use `this`, then please write `this->member`, but there is no need to do this within the scope of the class (there are rare exceptions) and commonly it is frowned upon in favor of simply writing `member`.

PS: The error you report is from different code, not the one you posted.